# SQL Error: Cannot be converted to a PACKED DECIMAL value

Tags: sql, import, db2, decimal

I have db2 import statement which reads from a file and writes to a database.

`Column data type for column 18` (where i am getting error) is `Decimal(18,2)`

The value for that column coming in the file is `-502.47`

However, I am getting the below error:

```
SQL3123W  The field value in row "1" and column "18" cannot be converted to a PACKED DECIMAL value.  A null was loaded.
```

And the value is not going into database.

What is the reason for this error ? What is the solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with the number of column. I was passing more number of columns then the program expected. So we can get above error in that case as well.

Answer (score 0):

It was because of the double quotes in the loaded CSV files at that particular cell mentioned in the error. 
You should try opening the file in Notepad++ or any other text editor, remove the double quotes, save and load back into the DB.

Your error should be resolved.